# Is it possible to affect a variable when the programm goes in a specific expression?

Tags: python, python-3.x, parsing

I want to know if my programm goes in a specific expression, and do something like this :

```
bool = False
ident = Word(alphas, alphanums + "_$").setName("identifier") # get bool = True here
```

Does python allow to do things like these or not ?

Comment: You can check `ident` value after the setting it's value, and then set the bool to true.

Comment: My program is a grammar, it will set the value of all the different words (e.g. ```ident``` ) and then go in only some of them, depending on the code I give him

Comment: Please give an example of input, and expected output

Comment: input : "123" 
```bool = False```
input : "abc"
```bool = True```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not fully sure what your program does, even with the input and output examples you wrote. It sounds like you want to execute some code, and then check if its result is contained in a defined list.

You can do it as follows:

```
bool_ = False
true_list = ["abc", "cde"]
ident = Word(alphas, alphanums + "_$").setName("identifier")

if ident in true_list:
    bool_ = True
```

You need to define the values you want the boolean to be changed to True, in `true_list`. Then execute you code and check if the value is contained inside the list. Otherwise, it will be left as `False`